# Sql server function slow runtime

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2008

I have the following function that returns the averages of the records by Group, Country, State and in turn by Season, Room Type etec. The problem with this function is that the response time is 15 minutes, can someone help me correct this problem please? I have also noticed that every time I run the function the response time increases

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnEstadisticosGruposNinios()
RETURNS  @tbEstadisticosGruposNinios TABLE 
(
    strGrupo nvarchar(255) NULL,
    strPais nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajePaisGrupo FLOAT null,
    strEstado  nvarchar(255)  NULL,
    nPorcentajeEstadoGrupo FLOAT NULL,
    intNinios INT NULL,
    nPorcentajeNiniosGrupo FLOAT NULL,
    strServicio nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajeServicio FLOAT NULL,
    strTipoHabitacion nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajeTipoHabitacion FLOAT NULL,
    strTarifa nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajeTarifa FLOAT NULL,
    strPaquete nvarchar(255)NULL,
    nPorcentajePaquete FLOAT NULL,
    intDiasEstancia INT NULL,
    nPorcentajeDiasEstancia FLOAT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @tbTemporalEstadisticosGruposNinios
        table (
            strGrupo nvarchar(255) NULL,
    strPais nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajePaisGrupo FLOAT null,
    strEstado  nvarchar(255)  NULL,
    nPorcentajeEstadoGrupo FLOAT NULL,
    intNinios INT NULL,
    nPorcentajeNiniosGrupo FLOAT NULL,
    strServicio nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajeServicio FLOAT NULL,
    strTipoHabitacion nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajeTipoHabitacion FLOAT NULL,
    strTarifa nvarchar(255) NULL,
    nPorcentajeTarifa FLOAT NULL,
    strPaquete nvarchar(255)NULL,
    nPorcentajePaquete FLOAT NULL,
    intDiasEstancia INT NULL,
    nPorcentajeDiasEstancia FLOAT NULL
        )

insert into @tbTemporalEstadisticosGruposNinios 

select tbGruposPais.strGrupo,tbGruposPais.strPais, tbGruposPais.nPorcentajePaisGrupo,
tbEstadosGrupos.strEstado,tbEstadosGrupos.nPorcentajeEstadoGrupo,
tbNiniosGrupos.intNinos,tbNiniosGrupos.nPorcentajeNiniosGrupo,
tbServiciosNinios.strServicio,tbServiciosNinios.nPorcentajeServicio,
tbTipoHabitacionNinios.strTipoHabitacion,
tbTipoHabitacionNinios.nPorcentajeTipoHabitacion,
tbTarifasNinios.strTarifa,
tbTarifasNinios.nPorcentajeTarifa,
tbPaqueteNinios.strPaquete,
tbPaqueteNinios.nPorcentajePaquete,
tbDiasEstanciaNinios.intDiasEstancia,
tbDiasEstanciaNinios.nPorcentajeDiasEstancia

 from

(select 
tbContadorPaisGrupo.strGrupo, 
 tbContadorPaisGrupo.strPais, 
 (CAST(tbContadorPaisGrupo.nContadorPais as float)*100/CAST(tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo.nRegistrosGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajePaisGrupo
  FROM
(select strGrupo, strPais, COUNT(strPais) nContadorPais from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento
  group by strGrupo,strPais
) tbContadorPaisGrupo,
(select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nRegistrosGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento
            group by strGrupo) tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo 
    where tbContadorPaisGrupo.strGrupo=tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo.strGrupo )tbGruposPais,

/*Consulta que obtiene el porcentaje de Estados por Grupo y Pais*/
(select 
 tbContadorEstadoGrupo.strGrupo, 
 tbContadorEstadoGrupo.strPais, 
 tbContadorEstadoGrupo.strEstado,
 (CAST(tbContadorEstadoGrupo.nContadorEstado as float)*100/CAST(tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo.nRegistrosGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajeEstadoGrupo
  FROM
(select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado, COUNT(strEstado) as nContadorEstado from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento    
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado) tbContadorEstadoGrupo,
(select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nRegistrosGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento
            group by strGrupo) tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo 
    where tbContadorEstadoGrupo.strGrupo=tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo.strGrupo) tbEstadosGrupos,
(select 
 tbContadorNiniosGrupo.strGrupo, 
 tbContadorNiniosGrupo.strPais, 
 tbContadorNiniosGrupo.strEstado,
 tbContadorNiniosGrupo.intNinos,
 (CAST(tbContadorNiniosGrupo.nContadorNinios as float)*100/CAST(tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo.nRegistrosGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajeNiniosGrupo
  FROM
(select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos, COUNT(intNinos) as nContadorNinios from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento    
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos) tbContadorNiniosGrupo,
(select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nRegistrosGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento
            group by strGrupo) tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo 
    where tbContadorNiniosGrupo.strGrupo=tbContadorRegistrosPorGrupo.strGrupo) tbNiniosGrupos,

( select  t1.strGrupo,t2.nContadorGrupo,t1.strPais,t1.strEstado,t1.intNinos,t1.strServicio, (CAST(t1.nContadorServicioNinios*100 as float)/CAST(t2.nContadorGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajeServicio from
 (select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strServicio,
 COUNT (strServicio) as nContadorServicioNinios from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento 
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strServicio) as t1,
 (select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nContadorGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento group by strGrupo) as t2  where t2.strGrupo=t1.strGrupo
)tbServiciosNinios,
 ( select  t1.strGrupo,t2.nContadorGrupo,t1.strPais,t1.strEstado,t1.intNinos,t1.strTipoHabitacion, (CAST(t1.nContadorTipoHabitacionNinios*100 as float)/CAST(t2.nContadorGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajeTipoHabitacion from
 (select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strTipoHabitacion,
 COUNT (strTipoHabitacion) as nContadorTipoHabitacionNinios from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento 
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strTipoHabitacion) as t1,
 (select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nContadorGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento group by strGrupo) as t2  where t2.strGrupo=t1.strGrupo
)tbTipoHabitacionNinios,
 ( select  t1.strGrupo,t2.nContadorGrupo,t1.strPais,t1.strEstado,t1.intNinos,t1.strTarifa, (CAST(t1.nContadorTarifaNinios*100 as float)/CAST(t2.nContadorGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajeTarifa from
 (select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strTarifa,
 COUNT (strTarifa) as nContadorTarifaNinios from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento 
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strTarifa) as t1,
 (select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nContadorGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento group by strGrupo) as t2  where t2.strGrupo=t1.strGrupo
)tbTarifasNinios,
  ( select  t1.strGrupo,t2.nContadorGrupo,t1.strPais,t1.strEstado,t1.intNinos,t1.strPaquete, (CAST(t1.nContadorPaqueteNinios*100 as float)/CAST(t2.nContadorGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajePaquete from
 (select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strPaquete,
 COUNT (strPaquete) as nContadorPaqueteNinios from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento 
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,strPaquete) as t1,
 (select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nContadorGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento group by strGrupo) as t2  where t2.strGrupo=t1.strGrupo
)tbPaqueteNinios,
  ( select  t1.strGrupo,t2.nContadorGrupo,t1.strPais,t1.strEstado,t1.intNinos,t1.intDiasEstancia, (CAST(t1.nContadorDiasEstanciaNinios*100 as float)/CAST(t2.nContadorGrupo as float)) as nPorcentajeDiasEstancia from
 (select strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,intDiasEstancia,
 COUNT (intDiasEstancia) as nContadorDiasEstanciaNinios from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento 
group by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado,intNinos,intDiasEstancia) as t1,
 (select strGrupo,COUNT(strGrupo) as nContadorGrupo from tbConjuntoEntrenamiento group by strGrupo) as t2  where t2.strGrupo=t1.strGrupo
)tbDiasEstanciaNinios

    where tbGruposPais.strGrupo=tbEstadosGrupos.strGrupo 
    and tbGruposPais.strPais=tbEstadosGrupos.strPais

    and tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo=tbGruposPais.strGrupo
    and tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo=tbEstadosGrupos.strGrupo
    and tbNiniosGrupos.strPais=tbGruposPais.strPais
    and tbNiniosGrupos.strPais=tbEstadosGrupos.strPais
    and tbNiniosGrupos.strEstado=tbEstadosGrupos.strEstado

    and tbServiciosNinios.strGrupo=tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo
    and tbServiciosNinios.strPais=tbNiniosGrupos.strPais
    and tbServiciosNinios.strEstado=tbNiniosGrupos.strEstado
    and tbServiciosNinios.intNinos=tbNiniosGrupos.intNinos

    and tbTipoHabitacionNinios.strGrupo=tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo
    and tbTipoHabitacionNinios.strPais=tbNiniosGrupos.strPais
    and tbTipoHabitacionNinios.strEstado=tbNiniosGrupos.strEstado
    and tbTipoHabitacionNinios.intNinos=tbNiniosGrupos.intNinos

    and tbTarifasNinios.strGrupo=tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo
    and tbTarifasNinios.strPais=tbNiniosGrupos.strPais
    and tbTarifasNinios.strEstado=tbNiniosGrupos.strEstado
    and tbTarifasNinios.intNinos=tbNiniosGrupos.intNinos

    and tbPaqueteNinios.strGrupo=tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo
    and tbPaqueteNinios.strPais=tbNiniosGrupos.strPais
    and tbPaqueteNinios.strEstado=tbNiniosGrupos.strEstado
    and tbPaqueteNinios.intNinos=tbNiniosGrupos.intNinos

    and tbDiasEstanciaNinios.strGrupo=tbNiniosGrupos.strGrupo
    and tbDiasEstanciaNinios.strPais=tbNiniosGrupos.strPais
    and tbDiasEstanciaNinios.strEstado=tbNiniosGrupos.strEstado
    and tbDiasEstanciaNinios.intNinos=tbNiniosGrupos.intNinos
    order by strGrupo,strPais,strEstado

insert into @tbEstadisticosGruposNinios
SELECT strGrupo,strPais,nPorcentajePaisGrupo,strEstado,nPorcentajeEstadoGrupo,
intNinios,nPorcentajeNiniosGrupo,strServicio,nPorcentajeServicio,strTipoHabitacion,nPorcentajeTipoHabitacion,
strTarifa,nPorcentajeTarifa,strPaquete,nPorcentajePaquete,intDiasEstancia,nPorcentajeDiasEstancia FROM @tbTemporalEstadisticosGruposNinios;
return
END
```

Comment: Gonna need to see an execution plan for that one

Comment: What happens when you run the script outside of a user defined function? Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You can rewrite it as an inline tvf, which should help, but your query looks pretty complex still. - [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem, thanks to the link published by SqlZim, I improved my queries implementing inner join and full join and I reduced the time to a second or 2, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, thanks to the link published by SqlZim, I improved my queries implementing inner join and full join and I reduced the time to a second or 2, thank you very much.